# Find the number of homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_5 $to $S_5$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Find the number of homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_5 $to $S_5$.

Let $\phi $ be a homomorphism.Then $\dfrac{\mathbb Z_5 }{kerf}\cong Im f$.Now $Im f$ is a subgroup of $S_5$ .Since $kerf $ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_5$ hence $o(kerf )=1,5$

If it is $5$ then it is the trivial homomorphism .

How to proceed with the case when it is $1$?
Then it will be a monomorphism and $|Im f|=5$. How to find all morphisms?

Comment: Why is there $f$ and $\phi$?

Comment: Hint: if we know $f(1)$, we can deduce everything about $f$.

Comment: sorry it is a mistake @Nameless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to finish is to find all elements of order 5, or at least the number of them. This is because the image of any generator must have order 5, and you get a different homomorphism by sending a specific generator to different elements. The elements you are looking for are the 5-cycles, of which there are $5!/5$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $o(\ker f) = 1$, then $\text{Im } f \cong \mathbb{Z}_5$, so it is cyclic, and is generated by any of its nonidentity elements. Conversely, if $g \in S_5$ is an element of order $5$, then the homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to S_5$ characterized by $1 \mapsto g$ satisfies $\ker \phi \subseteq 5\mathbb{Z}$, so it descends to a homomorphism $\widetilde{\phi}: \mathbb{Z} / 5\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}_5 \to S_5$.

> So, we get one such homomorphism for each element of order $5$ in $S_5$. These are precisely the $5$-cycles, and there are $\frac{5!}{5} = 24$ of them; adding the trivial homomorphism gives that there are $25$ homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}_5 \to S_5$ in total.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful.